# Generating an index of values to compound, but ignoring initial value in a scalable way

Tags: r, lag, dplyr

I am trying to generate an index that is derived from return data.

The new column I want to generate would be derived by taking 100 and then compounding this.  For this example:

first value = 100

second value = first value*(1+10/100) = 110

third value = second value *(1+20/100) = 132 and so on

Note that the first return value of 5 needs to be ignored.  I know I can just overwrite it to accomplish what I want, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to get the desired output.

I come close to getting what I want, but I need to ignore the first return of 5.  The expected output of the new_col would be 100, 110, 132.

```
**Reproducible example**

    # Load package
    library(tidyverse)

    # Create data
    df <- data.frame(asset = c("A", "A", "A"), return = c(5,10,20))
    df

# Generate new column
test <- df %>%
  mutate(new_col = 100) %>%   #initialize
  mutate(new_col = ifelse(row_number(new_col) == 1,
                          new_col,
                          lag(new_col, 1) * cumprod((1 + return/100))
                          )
         )
test
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `accumulate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(newcol = accumulate(return[-1], ~ .x* (1 + .y/100), .init = 100))
#  asset return newcol
#1     A      5    100
#2     A     10    110
#3     A     20    132
```

---

Or using `cumprod`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(newcol = cumprod( c(100, 1 + return[-1]/100)))
```

---

Or similar option in `base R`

```
Reduce(function(x, y) x * (1 + y/100), df$return[-1], init = 100, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 100 110 132
```

---

Or with a `for` loop

```
df$newcol[1] <- 100
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) df$newcol[i] <- df$newcol[i-1] * (1 + df$return[i]/100)
```

---

For multiple columns, use `mutate_at`

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with('return')), 
      list(newcol = ~  accumulate(.[-1], ~ .x * (1+ .y/100), .init = 100)))
#   asset return return2 return_newcol return2_newcol
#1     A      5      15           100            100
#2     A     10      12           110            112
#3     A     20      25           132            140
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(asset = c("A", "A", "A"), 
      return = c(5,10,20), return2 = c(15, 12, 25))
```

Comment: Akrun, this is super helpful.  Would you mind explaining the accumulate solution?  I'm less familiar with the "~" operator and what it is doing here, as well as how .x refers to the return column and how .y refers to the newcol.  I read the documentation, but it wasn't clear that reduce was implied without calling the function, or whether this would work with more than 3 arguments (e.g., .z).  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, one other related question if you don't mind.  My real data set has numerous columns for which I want to do this operation.  I was trying to use mutate_at but couldn't make it work, so I used this simpler example to start where there was only one asset column

Comment: @DaveM It does work. e.g. `df <- data.frame(asset = c("A", "A", "A"), return = c(5,10,20), return2 = c(15, 12, 25));df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('return')), list(newcol = ~  accumulate(.[-1], ~ .x * (1+ .y/100), .init = 100)))`

Comment: Thanks.  I didn’t mean to imply it didn’t work. I meant when I had tried on a previous attempt (before your answer) I could not get it to work.

Comment: @DaveM No problem.  May be you missed a `~` or something